# What is the difference between application initializer and a service in ember?

Tags: ember.js

As I am new to ember, I got confused between the application initializer and a service. To my knowledge, both of them was doing the same job and both have the lifetime of the application. Could anyone please explain the difference between them with a clear example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application Initializer is a place where we initialize or Register or inject our new factory classes or any Services.
And Both services and Application Initializer initialized class(factory) can share their states like a singleton to every routes they were used .
Using applicationInstance.lookup() method we can even use any Application Initializer initialized  class in which they were'nt injected initially when they were created and can share their states as well

Answer (score 4):

Services can be injected into other areas of your app, where as application initializers cannot.

Services are useful for when you want to track app-level state, such as whether or not a sidebar is open/closed -- or if you want to manage the open/closed state of a modal -- or if you want to manage a websocket connection.  Because Services are injectable, they allow the other areas of your application to interact with the services' functions, properties, etc.

Application Initializers are actually only run during boot, during the *initialization* of the _application. A common pattern here is if you want to inject a service into all routes or something.

Docs on Initializers: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/initializers/

Docs on Services: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/services/

Comment: I think that the application initializers can also be injected into other areas of the app with the help of getOwner() and lookup() methods. Please explain me with some clear ideas...Thanks

Comment: I don't think you'd want to / I don't know if you'd get anything out of doing that. I can see that by running `Object.keys(window.requirejs.entries).filter(b => b.includes("initializer"))` that the initializers are in the D.I. container, but.... the initializers are only meant to be run when your app boots, I believe. :-\

Comment: Cool beans :) Welcome!

According to the docs on initializers, they just, by definition, have a different purpose: "Application instance initializers are run as an application instance is loaded. They provide a way to configure the initial state of your application, as well as to set up dependency injections that are local to the application instance (e.g. A/B testing configurations)."

and for Services: "Services are useful for features that require shared state or persistent connections."

Comment: So, if you've heard of redux (which is used for sharing application state between components), Services would be used for that purpose as well.

A common use case for an application initializer is to inject a service in to all components (like maybe you have some service for managing a websocket or something)

Comment: Also, in case you aren't familiar with dependency injection: There is a Depedency Injection container in which many aspects of the app / classes / instances of things are registered. This is just a global look up table of things in your app.

In a component or route, you can inject things from the D.I. container. This is done with some helpers such as `service` from `import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';`

Comment: This looks up the instance of the service _for you_ on the D.I. Container so you don't need to import the service yourself and worry about the state the service is in during the import.

Comment: @Raja.S.K for more information on Dependency Injection, the ember guides have a page on it: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/dependency-injection/

(I just learned about the existence of this page myself)