# Ember instance initializer

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

**I have following questions regarding using Ember instance initializer inside an addon/engine;**

1. Is there a naming convention to be followed for the instance initializer ?
2. At what point of time exactly is the instance initializer executed (when doing local ember build / ember server) ?
3. How can we debug or see values within the instance initializer ? (e.g. if I have code whoch checks appInstance.mountPoint, how do I print/see it's value within the debug/logs) ?

Comment: You might find some points here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051287/what-is-the-difference-between-application-initializer-and-a-service-in-ember

Comment: You might find some points here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051287/what-is-the-difference-between-application-initializer-and-a-service-in-ember

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a naming convention to be followed for the instance initializer ?

Well, call them about what they do. If you're an addon writer I would consider to name them like your addon.

> At what point of time exactly is the instance initializer executed (when doing local ember build / ember server) ?

The instance initialiser is called on the client. Maybe this was a misunderstanding, it is *not* called during `ember build` or `ember serve`! It's one of the first things happening when a web page opens the app. They are run after initialisers.

On Fastboot they are called for each request, in opposite to initialisers which are only called once.

> How can we debug or see values within the instance initializer ? (e.g. if I have code whoch checks appInstance.mountPoint, how do I print/see it's value within the debug/logs) ?

The same way you debug any JS code. You could add `debugger;` or do `console.log()`. Then ensure your JS console is open during page load. Probably its easier to open the JS console and then reload the page.

As mentioned the code is executed in the *browser*, so you won't get any log information in the ember development server console or during `ember build`.